# Google maps don't display circles with certain coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a set of data about earthquakes, which I need to display it on the google map using circles. At first I used marker to make sure maps work properly. Markers was displayed fine. Then I tried to draw circles with certain radius and coordinates the same as markers, unfortunately they wasn't drown. I found google's tutorial for circles with US cities, which works correct.

After some tests I understood that my problem somehow is related with point coordinates. I can't say what exactly wrong with coordinates, because they are object `{ lat: val, lng: val }` and there isn't any errors, circles just aren't displayed.

I made this [gist](https://codepen.io/QuarK26/pen/qxJbRE) (please don't steal my api key:)) in order to you can see it for yourself. Hope someone has enough experiences in google maps to know that is wrong (looks like there is no other way to understand the problem). I use google maps for the first time.

Comment: I can see the circles and markers in your maps. If you set to better  zoom level, may be`zoom: 2,` you would be able to see those circles and markers. Currently your are adding circle on map2 and marker on map1 and setting circle again on map2.

Comment: A `google.maps.LatLngLiteral` has the properties `{lat val:, lng: val}`,  not `{lat: val, long: val}`.

Comment: @soccerway Sorry, I did not make myself clear, the circles you see is city's circles, they are fine. The problem circles must be on `map2` on the same place as markers on `map1`.

Comment: @QuarK : if I did understood your problem correctly, circles has got different '{lat val:, lng: val}' and markers got different lat, lng values right ? In this case how can circles draw on the same place on map 2 as markers on map1. If you need in that way, both circles and markers need to have same lat lng values.

Comment: @soccerway No, they have the same lat and lng values. They both use `testEvents` object.

Comment: The markers are at a latitude of 85+ degrees which doesn't work so well with the projection used on google maps (it is in/close to the grey area).  The radius of the circles is also rather small (~1.5 meters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]As advised by geocodezip, if the calculated 'radius' values are too small may be the reason for not drawing the circle.
As per below calculation, radio is calculated as 2 to the power of 3.3 or 2 raised to 3.3 ( magnitude ), which is 9.849 divided by 2 = 4.924 which is the small to plot for a circle I guess.

**Calculation:**
radius: Math.pow(2, testEvents[event].magnitude) / 2.0

So I have increased the magnitude values to 17.3, 17.4, 15.4, 15.3 for all of the testEvents objects 
and now I am able to see the circles for those markers; see the screen shot attached. Fiddle link attached too.

```
[![<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<style>
.map {
    height: 500px;
}
</style>
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 map" id="map1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6 map" id="map2"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script async defer
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=your_api_key&callback=initMap">
</script>


<script>
var map1;
var map2;

var citymap = {
    chicago: {
        center: { lat: 41.878, lng: -87.629 },
        population: 2714856
    },
    newyork: {
        center: { lat: 40.714, lng: -74.005 },
        population: 8405837
    },
    losangeles: {
        center: { lat: 34.052, lng: -118.243 },
        population: 3857799
    },
    vancouver: {
        center: { lat: 49.25, lng: -123.1 },
        population: 603502
    }
};

var testEvents = {
    0: {
        point: { lat: 85.09, lng: 15.91 },
        magnitude: 17.3
    },
    1: {
        point: { lat: 84.22, lng: 2.85 },
        magnitude: 17.4
    },
    2: {
        point: { lat: 85.04, lng: 11.79 },
        magnitude: 15.4
    },
    3: {
        point: { lat: 85.25, lng: 13.22 },
        magnitude: 15.3
    }
};

function initMap() {
    map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map1'), {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(74.370702, 34.767772),
        mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    });
    map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map2'), {
        zoom: 2,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(74.370702, 34.767772),
        mapTypeId: 'satellite'
    });

    WriteQuakeEvents();
}

function WriteQuakeEvents() {
      for (var city in citymap) {
        // Add the circle for this city to the map.
        var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map: map2,
            center: citymap\[city\].center,
            radius: Math.sqrt(citymap\[city\].population) * 100
        });
    }

    for (var event in testEvents) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: testEvents\[event\].point,
            map: map1
        });
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            strokeColor: '#FFFFFF',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            map: map1,
            center: testEvents\[event\].point,
            radius: Math.pow(2, testEvents\[event\].magnitude) / 2.0
        });
    }
}
</script>

</div>
</body>
</html>][1]][1]
```

**[//Fiddle here:](https://jsfiddle.net/scrumvisualize/fvLhsdor/)**

Comment: Well, this is very strange, I had tried to set some constant radiuses like 100, but nothing has changed. Anyway, now it's working, thank you.

Comment: Well, this is very strange, I had tried to set some constant radiuses like 100, but nothing has changed. Anyway, now it's working, thank you.